# Error running linear transformation scene in manim

Tags: manim

```
%%manim LinearTransformationSceneExample
from manimlib import *
from manimlib.scene.vector_space_scene import LinearTransformationScene

class LinearTransformationSceneExample(LinearTransformationScene):
    def __init__(self):
        LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
         
        )

    def construct(self):
        matrix = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
        self.apply_matrix(matrix)
        self.wait()
```

I get an error

TypeError: LinearTransformationSceneExample.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'camera_config'

How do I fix this?